# DNS wont resolve on Fedora 37

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, dns, ipv4

I just installed Fedora 37 on my laptop and cannot get the DNS to resolve despite attempting every remedy I’m capable of completing.

I am new to Linux and do not understand the jargon, I can use the terminal but I don’t know what I’m actually doing.

I can connect to WiFi networks, but I cannot load websites as the DNS won’t resolve the IP for the website. I have attempted to modify /etc/resolv.conf and use my selected nameserver, this worked the first time but after rebooting this was wiped. And even after repeating the same modification it will not work again.

I tried to change the DNS using the GUI to Google, Cloudflare, OpenDNS and my routers default servers but none of them worked. When I ping 192.168.1.254 I get back “no buffer available” which I assume means it didn’t work. And when I tried “host www.apple.com” I got a nameserver error.

I don’t know what’s wrong but it’s something to do with Fedora as every other devices works great on my network and even my laptop did when running windows.

Any help is greatly appreciated and I will endeavour to provide anymore information that you need. I need to use my laptop for University work and as much as I’d like to learn how to use Linux it is just a hobby and I have to put Uni first. If I can’t sort this in a few days it’ll be back to Windows.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you executed `sudo dnf distro-sync`?  Are you using Gnome? When you go to Settings-->Wi-Fi and select settings for your connection (the little gear-like icon), under `IPv4` and `IPv6`, is everthing set to `Automatic`?

Comment: If you boot from the [Fedora 37 Live ISO](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/ "There's a download link here -->"), do you have DNS issues then?